# How to Fix Generic File Icons in macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina, icon

How to restore file icons when they have gone generic in Mac OS Catalina ?

Comment: It's absolutely fine & even encouraged to ask & answer your own question - but it should be in the form of a distinct Question [with a nice googlable title too] then a separate Answer [which you can then mark yourself as 'Accepted'] See https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer …and don't put 'solved' in the title, the answer being marked as accepted does that job.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ak! makes perfect sense. Will do.

Answer (score 3):

Rebuild the LaunchServices Cache using this terminal command (Tested and works on macOS Catalina 10.15.2):

```
sudo /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

**DropBox Note:** 
If you have Dropbox running, you may have to: 1) restart the mac. 2) Pause Syncing and wait for a minute or two. 3) Resume syncing. This should force DropBox to rescan the shares and re-attribute the files and folders.

Answer (score -1):

I use an application called [LiteIcon](https://freemacsoft.net/liteicon/) to change and/or restore icons.